# Polygons with images

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

I am trying to do some shapes together with *CSS*.
[image: polygons with images inside]

How can I make these shapes with the images inside?

Comment: Yes possible!!! I hope this is not the answer you want to know

Comment: How it possible  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach using:

- [inline svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG)
- the [pattern element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/pattern)
- the [polygon element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon)

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 6.1">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="6" height="4">
      <image xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="6" height="4" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <g fill="url(#img)" stroke-width="0.1" stroke="lightgrey">
    <polygon points="0.3 0.3 5.5 0.3 3.4 3.1 0.3 3.1" />
    <polygon points="0.3 3.3 5.6 3.3 7.5 5.8 0.3 5.8" />
    <polygon points="5.7 0.3 4.65 1.75 7.7 5.8 9.7 5.8 9.7 0.3" />
    <polygon points="4.52 1.85 5.5 3.15 3.6 3.15" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Mozilla not supporting

Comment: What verion are you using @user5533614 for me it works fine in Firefox

Comment: nice solution @web-tiki

Comment: @ web-tiki , Mozilla version 47.0.1

Comment: @user5533614 I use the same version and it works fine.